# Traverse C# collection from CSHTML in JQUERY

Tags: c#, jquery, collections

My View(cshtml) has around 10 **div** tags at root level. 
Each **div** has nested multiple **div** inside it. 
The HTML code is below. As there is foreach loop, i have multiple such DIV

```html
    foreach(var result in results)
{
<div class="itemRow" id= value data-List=@invoiceDetail>

    <div class="itemStatus paid"><span>Paid</span></div>
    <div class="itemDetails" style="display: none;">
        <div class="itemContainer">
            <div class="left">   <table class="stripes"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="itemContainer" id="_orderId">  <h4>Order details</h4> </div>
        <div class="itemContainer">
            <div class="left"> <strong>Download PDF</strong></a> </div>
            <div class="right">  You can download paper invoice </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border hundra"><div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Each **div** at root has an attribute **data-List** from server side. This attribute has a c# Collection as value. I need to read the value from **data-List** attribute of that particular **div** and traverse through it.

I tried to use the **.attr** method but what i received the data type of the collection.

Please suggest a way forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your html code, that will be much better to suggest you changes and solution instead of reading through all the theoretical analysis

Comment: Brother your requirement is not clear.. Can you put your code here.. It will give better understanding to us .. :)